# How I can send data using laravel connected Postgresql to received data from android application?

Tags: android, laravel, postgresql

I'm currently working on an android project. And I want to upload some data from android app to (web(using bootstrap)+API)_(Laravel). My lecturor said that now I have to write code API to manage datas but I don't know how to do that. I searched so much but my results that build GET, POST, EDIT, DELETE and build Controller for Laravel project. How should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've copied is just plain PHP and has nothing do do with Laravel at all. If you actually want your backend to be Laravel you'll need to ditch your code above and actually learn to use Laravel.

Comment: I don't know where to start? This is plain PHP code and has nothing to do with Laravel. What exactly do you want to achieve? Laravel uses a database abstraction layer, so it doesn't really matter if you're using MySQL or Postgresql. If it's a pure API, I would also suggest to take a look at Laravel Lumen instead of using a full-fledged Laravel app. If you need a backoffice to go with it, then you can stick with Laravel.

Comment: And @Mart for the love of god, erase that awful code from your post, no matter where you got it from, before anyone actually uses this. This has all the worst practices in it and will make SQL injections a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) to manage Http requests and responses to the laravel server. And use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for managing JSON objects from the android application.

Make a JSON object containing the data you want to send and return the JSON string from the Laravel application.

Comment: Laravel application you said manages project's data as my lecturor said?

Comment: You have to develop the API part on the Laravel Application as your lecturer said. In which case do you need help with? The android part or the Laravel part?

Comment: I found that I had mistake that my lecturer said that I have to code Java App Server but I chose Laravel. I think I'm wrong. And now I'm going to choose Boostrap + Apache Tomcat + Spark + OrmLite  instead. I don't know it's ok ỏ not? Do you have any advices for me?

Comment: Use JSON to retrieve and send data from the server and it'll be easy to handle when it comes to the Android application.